# Getting a Javascript error that property is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am struggling to solve this issue. Please look into my code below.

```
function GenericFormHandler(templateId, webService) {
   this.templateId = templateId;
   this.webService = webService;
}

GenericFormHandler.prototype.process = function(form, success, failure) {
    var request= form.serializeArray(); 
    this.webService(request,
        function(data) {
            success(data);
        },
        function(status) {
            failure(status);
        });
};
```

I am getting error at **this.webService.** I am running below function with

```
 function createAccount() {
                var form = $("#login");
                $(form).validationEngine();
                if (!$(form).validationEngine('validate'))
                {
                    return false;
                }

                var handler = new GenericFormHandler('#template','$.ws.userSignUpRequest');
                handler.process(form, function() {
                    window.location.href = "home.html";
                }, function(error) {

                });
            }
            ;
```

I am accessing webService property in method process but it giving me error as property of an object is not a function. How to solve this error?

Comment: you pass string in constructor, not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.ws.userSignUpRequest` is this the reference of the function , then pass it with out the string

```
var handler = new GenericFormHandler('#template', $.ws.userSignUpRequest);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code `this.webService` is set to a string. A string is not a method which can be called

```
this.webService(request, ... // you passed the string '$.ws.userSignUpRequest' to this
```

if `$.ws.userSignUpRequest` is actually a reference to the webservice (as I suspect it is) then you should pass it directly (without quotes) to the constructor of `GenericFormHandler`

```
var handler = new GenericFormHandler('#template',$.ws.userSignUpRequest);
```